# htaccess redirect language folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to redirect all incoming requests in a .htaccess file that match the following ruleset.

```
domain.com -> www.domain.com/en (en is default language)

domain.com/foo -> www.domain.com/en/foo

domain.com/foo?bar=baz -> www.domain.com/en/foo?bar=baz

www.domain.com -> www.domain.com/en
...
```

If a request contains a language parameter from a given list (en|fr|de) there should be no redirect to 'en'.

Example:

```
domain.com/de/foo/whatever?bar=baz -> www.domain.com/de/foo/whatever?bar=baz
```

What I have so far is just the redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I really hope someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|fr|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This ruleset relies on user's language settings. It should not. I'd like to have just plain URL redirecting.

Comment: Okay. Took a different approach.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Cheers